Map between Invertible Sheaves(not?) always injective
Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ two invertible sheaves, i.e. locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of rank $1$, or equivalently that every $x \in X$ is contained in some appropriate (Zariski) open neighborhood $U \subset X$ such that the restriction of $\mathcal{M}$ to $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_U$ as $\mathcal{O}_U$-module.
Question: Is it correct that there is in general no reason why a nonzero map $\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$ between invertible sheaves (regarded as map of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) should be injective?
The point is the following: First of all, we can work locally ( even stalkwise) and thus may assume that $X= \text{Spec}(A)$ is affine (even local after passing to stalks) and $M,N$ are assumed to be free $A$-modules in the sense that there exist non torsion elements $m \in M, n \in N$ (ie $\text{Ann}_A(m) = \text{Ann}_A(n) =\{0\}$, such that we have $A$-module isomorphisms
$A \to M, 1 \mapsto m$ (and analogously with $N$ and $n $).
Now the problem is that a nontrivial morphism $M \to N$ could map $m $ to certain $a \cdot n$ (where $a \in A$ such that we obtain neccessarily obtain following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{1_A \mapsto a}  >> A \\
@VV1_A \mapsto mV  @VV1_A \mapsto nV  \\
M @>{m \mapsto a \cdot n}>> N;
\end{CD}
$$
But this $a \in A$ could be a zero divisor in $A$ (...at least I not see any reason which should garantee that this cannot happen) and therefore horizontal maps (as $A$-module maps) fail to be injective.
Could somebody check if the reasonings I sketched above are correct so far? If yes, then it would be indeed consequestly not true that any map between invertible sheaves is injective, if I'm not confusing something? (The motivation is that I several times read that if there exist a nontrivial section $s \in H^0(X, \mathcal{L})$ of invertible sheaf $L$, then one can consider map $s:\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{L}$ induced by this $s$ and one often claim that it is injective. But following my reasonings above it seems that for arbitrary $X$ it not neccessarily should be true; one needs additional assumption that $X$ is integral).

Consider $A=\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and let $M=N$ be free of rank one. Then multiplication by $(0,1)$ is not injective. So yes, your reasoning is correct.
